# Java Script API V3.6 displays base maps in a chequered pattern

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am currently running ARC GIS for Server 10.1 on an intranet. I have installed the Java Script API V 3.6. I am currently trying to view a cached image service using the Java Script API. When the service loads the tiles do not load in their proper places. Does any one know a fix for this?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot?  Have you reviewed the traffic using a tool like Fiddler (fiddler2.com) to see if some tile requests are being blocked?

Answer (score 2):

Does your map look similar to the screen shot shown under "re-factored css" here:  https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/new_v32.html

The fix is to include the [required CSS](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/css.html) for the API. For instance, for version 3.6:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.6/js/esri/css/esri.css">
```

Comment: Yes it does. I do have the esri.css sheet in my ArcGIS for Server 10.1 directory structure and have tried adding @import "http:\\Server-Name\arcgis_js_api\ibrary\3.6\3.6\js\esri\esri\css\esri.css to the mapServerJSAPI and am hoping it will work once I can reset my server. I will download the esri.css again if this does not work. Thank you for your time :)